# Auto-casting number literals in a type checker

Tags: type-conversion, compiler-construction, programming-languages, typechecking

I am working on a compiler and I have this issue. Here are the current rules.

```
let x := 100;        // x is i64
let x := 100 as i32; // x is i32
let x : i32 = 100;   // type error i64 and i32 don't match
```

Right now all literals that are not determined to be floats are typed as signed 64 bit numbers. In the last example, because the type checker is trying to match `i32` to `i64` we get an error.

I want to be clear that I am not looking for soething like this. This is what I see people meaning when talking about type inference but I am not looking for this. In this example I want this to give an error as the literal with out a given type shuold be `i64`.

```
fn foo(x: i32) void {}

let x := 100; // x's type is yet to be determined or constrained by the context
foo(x);       // x is infered as i32
```

So I am asking for adivce to solve the first issue.

One more thing to note is that I am not just trying to do this for assignments but in other locations aswell like function calls and struct instantiation.

Thank you in advance.

Here is a link I found discussing bi-directional typing in Haskell but compared to what I am doing this seems complex and difficult to actually find out how to implement.

[Link](https://www.haskellforall.com/2022/06/the-appeal-of-bidirectional-type.html)